Is the statement in Brahma-Vaivarta purana that Siva is Satvik unusual coming from a Vaishnavite Purana?
https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/mode/2up
BRAHMA-KHANDA, CHAPTER 8 (29)

This enraged, Brahma, the creator of the
universe. О Lord, on getting enraged, Brahma, a
Rudra appeared out of his forehead. He is said to
be Kalagni Rudra and is known as the one with
tamoguna element in the universe. Brahma is
known as rajas, besides, Siva and Visnu are
taken to be Satvikas. The great Krsna, the lord of
Goloka is formless and beyond nature. The
foolish people, term Siva as possessing the
tamasis elements, but he is spotless, truthful and
the foremost of the Vaispavas

It seems more usual for Vaishnavite Puranas to characterize Siva as Tamasic.  Are there other such examples from other Vaishnavite Puranas?

Lord Shiva is on the level of shuddha-sattva being always situated in samādhi, and so is Bhagavan Vishnu. Are you looking for the above translation in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana?

Thanks for asking for clarification.  Made the question more specific. @harihara

Lord Shiva being characterised as Sattvik, Rajasic, or Tamasic in the gross sense is a misunderstanding since He is completely spiritual.
Lord Shiva has been called as Tāmasī due to His involvement in the acts of annhilation (similar to Lord Sankarshana who is said to reside below Patala) but never Tamasic.
Let's look at Shrimad Bhagavatam which is said to be the most authoritive among the Puranas which are said to be Sattvika.
In the Bhagavatam 8.7, Shiva is glorified by the Prajapatis as Parabrahman.

त्वं ब्रह्म परमं गुह्यं सदसद्भ‍ावभावनम् । नानाशक्तिभिराभातस्त्वमात्मा
जगदीश्वर: ॥ २४ ॥
You are the cause of all causes, the self-effulgent, inconceivable,
impersonal Brahman, which is originally Parabrahman. You manifest
various potencies in this cosmic manifestation.

Lord Shiva is constantly worshipped by the personalities known as ātma-rāma i.e., those who have fully attained self-realization and factually remain merged in the bliss of the atman.

ये त्वात्मरामगुरुभिर्हृदि चिन्तिताङ्‍‍घ्रि- द्वन्द्वं चरन्तमुमया
तपसाभितप्तम् । कत्थन्त उग्रपरुषं निरतं श्मशाने ते नूनमूतिमविदंस्तव
हातलज्जा: ॥ ३३ ॥
Exalted, self-satisfied persons who preach to the entire world think
of your lotus feet constantly within their hearts. However, when
persons who do not know your austerity see you moving with Umā, they
misunderstand you to be lusty, or when they see you wandering in the
crematorium they mistakenly think that you are ferocious and envious.
Certainly they are shameless. They cannot understand your activities.

PS: The Puranas extoll one personality as Supreme over another based on the Vedic principles of raso vai sah (The Supreme Lord is the reservoir of all pleasure) and eka bahu syām (He expands Himself into many thousands and millions but still remain One).
Such glorifications of the Absolute Truth do not depend on the mundane acceptance and rejection of the Puranas by the society and attempts to denounce them.
Slowly, this so-called intellectual quest and self-study of our vast Pauranic literatures may creep into the Vedas and Upanishads too in the future due to an inherent decline in the capacity to appreciate oneness through plurality, lack of acceptance of a Guru, and today's modern approaches to learning which lack a Vedic origin.

Thanks, but my question is only whether Siva is characterized as "Satvik" in any other Vaishnavite scripture.  @harihara

Shiva is characterized as Parabrahman in Shrimad Bhagavatam which is a Vaishnava Purana, which automatically makes Him Sattvik (and much greater). Thanks for reading.

The very fact that the classification of Puranas or Devatas on the basis of Gunas is never mentioned in any text except the Puranas themselves (most of which are highly interpolated and have grave inconsistencies across recensions) is enough to conclude that the concept is not pramanik but a sampradayik work. Even more, the classifications is not same in Puranas but varies according to which kind of (Vaishnava Pradhana/Shaiva Pradhana) Purana you are reading.
The Shrutis equivocally declare both Rudra/Shiva and Vishnu to be non-different from Parabrahman(as his highest manifestations) and hence transcend and control both Gunas and Maya (Gunas come into existence by primordial Maya or Prakriti).
Hence the statement is not unusual in the sense that not all sections of a Purana need to be in consonance with the broad characterisation of the Purana as well as the fact that the concept itself being a later one will not be consistent across Puranas.
